# Get value type of std::map which passed to template function

Tags: c++, dictionary, templates

Having a template function -

```
template <class B>
B getValue (B& map) {
    // implementation ...       
}
```

To this function a pass a `map` , like  -

```
map<string,double> doubleMap;
getValue (doubleMap);
```

So for example in this case,  if I want to set the *return value* of the function to `double` according to `doubleMap` I should extract the `value` *type* of this `map`  , also if I want to declare on a double (or any other type according to the passed map) I must have this  ..

How can I get it ?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`std::map` defines the member types `key_type` and `mapped_type`.

What you want is `B::mapped_type`, which will be `double` in your case.

Answer (score 2):

You can create a template that receives a container and exports its type arguments with a typedef: (an example for general tamplate argument type retrieval)

```
template <typename>
class GetTemplateArgs {};

template <typename ARG1, typename ARG2>
class GetTemplateArgs<std::map<ARG1,ARG2>>
{
  public:
    typedef ARG1 KEY;
    typedef ARG2 DATA;
};

template <class B>
typename GetTemplateArgs<B>::DATA getValue (B& map) {
    // implementation ...       
}
```

And of course you can then make it more specific for a map, so it will only recieve a map as the argument.

Answer (score 0):

Just in case it helps, here is an example of how I do it:

```
    template<typename MapType>
    static auto GetValueOrDefault(const MapType& map, const std::string& key, const typename MapType::mapped_type& defaultVal)
    {
        // Try to find the key
        auto iter = map.find(key);
        
        // If we didn't find it then return the default value
        if (iter == map.end())
            return defaultVal;

        // Return the value
        return iter->second;
    }
```

This is similar to arnoo's answer, but the one additional piece I had to do was add the keyword 'typename' before "MapType::mapped_type" in the function parameter list.